# Loading more items from database

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm new to ajax/C# sharp and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get more item from he database, when the user scrolls down.

I have a webpage where there are a bunch of comments (Something like Twitter), and it starts by displaying the first 19 comments.

Which is the best way to reach the bottom and make the database display the next 19 comments and so on and so on?

Here is my code:

**C# Sharp code with HTML**

```
 @foreach (var photo in db.Query(photos, galleryId))
        {
            var hash2 = "@" + photo.UserName;
            <div class="comment1" class="com-@photo.Id">
                <div class="comment2">
                     <div class="doce">
                        <div class="uno_2">
                            <div class="picpic">
                                <img alt="miniatura" style="display: none" src="@Href("~/Photo/Thumbnail3", photo.UserId, new { size="medium" })" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="dos_2">
                             <strong>
                                 <a href="~/User/View/@photo.UserId" class="nombresito" title="Ver el perfil de @(photo.Nombre)">@photo.Nombre @photo.Apellido </a><span class="hash">@hash2</span>
                             </strong>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="veintidos_2">
                        <div class="tres_3">
                            <div class="commenttext">@photo.CommentText</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        }
```

**Javascript (this is triggered automatically by an onLoad() function**

```
        var xmlhttp;
        var link = "/more?more=" + 19;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("com1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("POST", link, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

**C# Sharp**

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
   var galleryId = UrlData[0].AsInt();
var more = Request.QueryString["more"];


     var photos = "SELECT TOP 19 * FROM Photos INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON Photos.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId ORDER BY Id DESC";


}
```

Comment: this link should help you get going, http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might help you: 
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll/comment-page-1

It's backend is focused on PHP, but you could easily do it with ASP.NET even easier. You can just leave javascript as is, except of few little modifications. Most important, you should replace the post request uri

```
$.post('~/api/LoadMore',{'page': track_load}, function(data){
```

Then, in your asp.net mvc web api you should have a method with matching name

```
IEnumerable<Comment> LoadMore(int page)
{
    //Return comments
}
```

If you are confused about web api, you can start here: http://www.asp.net/web-api